# Only show important birthdays on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I manage the list people who show up on my calendar on their birthdays?

I also want each birthday reminder to show the age the person is turning that day.

Should I be using a different calendar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Calendar simply shows the birthdays of your Google Contacts. There is no way to restrict what people are displayed except by removing the birthday data from your Contacts.

(Of course, there's nothing stopping you from creating a calendar with just the birthdays of the important people you want to see. That's what I used to do before Calendar started reading from Contacts.)

Google also does not have an option to show the age someone is going to be with their birthday entry on your calendar.

You'll need to find another calendar to do that (if one exists). Finding such an app is beyond the ken of this site, however.